# Не могу спарсить данные из yandex

Tags: python, парсер

Ссылка с которой я хочу парсить: [https://yandex.ru/search/?clid=2358536&text=доллар+в+рубли&l10n=ru&lr=65](https://yandex.ru/search/?clid=2358536&text=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80+%D0%B2+%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8&l10n=ru&lr=65)

Пытаюсь написать парсер для курса валют на Python, но вместо страницы с dom деревом yandex я получаю это:

<!doctype html>Ð¹!Ð¾Ð´ÑÐ²ÐµÑÐ´Ð¸ÑÐµ, ÑÑÐ¾ Ð·Ð°Ð¿ÑÐ¾ÑÑ Ð¾ÑÐ¿ÑÐ°Ð²Ð»ÑÐ»Ð¸ Ð²Ñ, Ð° Ð½Ðµ ÑÐ¾Ð±Ð¾Ñ</spa
n>ÐÐµÐ½Ñ Ð¶Ð°Ð»Ñ, Ð½Ð¾ Ð·Ð°Ð
¿ÑÐ¾ÑÑ Ñ Ð²Ð°ÑÐµÐ³Ð¾ ÑÑÑÑÐ¾Ð¹ÑÑÐ²Ð° Ð¿Ð¾Ñ
Ð¾Ð¶Ð¸ Ð½Ð° Ð°Ð²ÑÐ¾Ð¼Ð°ÑÐ¸ÑÐµÑÐºÐ¸Ðµ.Â Ð¾ÑÐµÐ¼Ñ ÑÑÐ¾ Ð¼Ð¾Ð³Ð»Ð¾ Ð¿ÑÐ¾Ð¸Ð·Ð¾Ð¹ÑÐ¸
?Ð¯ Ð½Ðµ ÑÐ¾Ð±Ð¾ÑÐÐµ, ÑÑÐ¾Ð±Ñ Ð¿ÑÐ¾Ð´Ð¾Ð»Ð¶Ð¸ÑÑÐÑÐ»Ð¸ Ñ
Ð²Ð°Ñ Ð²Ð¾Ð·Ð½Ð¸ÐºÐ»Ð¸ Ð¿ÑÐ¾Ð±Ð»ÐµÐ¼Ñ, Ð¿Ð¾Ð¶Ð°Ð»ÑÐ¹ÑÑÐ°, Ð²Ð¾ÑÐ¿Ð¾Ð»ÑÐ·ÑÐ¹ÑÐµÑÑÂ Ñ
Ð¾ÑÐ¼Ð¾Ð¹ Ð¾Ð±ÑÐ°ÑÐ½Ð¾Ð¹ ÑÐ²ÑÐ·Ð¸</a

> window.**SSR_DATA**={url:"/ru/checkbox",reqId:"1646947148752647-17804477116503538913-vla2-8593-8b6-vla-l7-balancer-8080-BAL",invalid:"no",formAction:"/checkcaptcha?key=9c805d5c-ca51240f-5c055520-a972af1_2%2F1646947148%2F009b993ae3bca49a3f73ab2320e48c98_f7577b8090daf8e9c05a45a83b8af693&retpath=https%3A%2F%2Fyandex.ru%2Fsearch%3Fclid%3D2358536%26text%3D%25D0%25B4%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B0%25D1%2580%2B%25D0%25B2%2B%25D1%2580%25D1%2583%25D0%25B1%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B8%26l10n%3Dru%26lr%3D65_d07f17a12e1bc5009865764be53aa03d&u=dbd0d727-785e7cc1-8107ef0-69d2e445",captchaKey:"9c805d5c-ca51240f-5c055520-a972af1_2/1646947148/009b993ae3bca49a3f73ab2320e48c98_f7577b8090daf8e9c05a45a83b8af693",imageSrc:"",voiceSrc:"",introSrc:"",aesKey:"PVErVfrPnfyfiJXA7orUyYGFfJ/FFScG2dWrK4gtJ6Y=",aesSign:"1_1646947148_18042132898345442674_5934c2706ad3ad1e5606d47f70e13443"}!function(e,t,n,a,c){e.ym=e.ym||function(){(e.ym.a=e.ym.a||[]).push(arguments)},e.ym.l=+new Date,a=t.createElement(n),c=t.getElementsByTagName(n)[0],a.async=1,a.src="https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js",c.parentNode.insertBefore(a,c)}(window,document,"script"),ym(10630330,"init",{clickmap:!0,trackLinks:!0,accurateTrackBounce:!0,webvisor:!0,ut:"noindex",params:{req_id:"1646947148752647-17804477116503538913-vla2-8593-8b6-vla-l7-balancer-8080-BAL"}})</div

Что это? Почему мне вместо нормальной страницы приходит это? Тут нет полей input, которые есть на странице.

Comment: Яндекс не любит ботоводов

Comment: Он в один день всё парсил, без ошибок, а потом перестал

Answer (score 1):

Яндекс березт эти данные из центробанка, об этом написано ниже прод курсом доллара.
У центробанка есть API, используйте его, парсить ничего не нужно, данные отдают сразу. Яндекс так же работает через этот API.
https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]